# Developing an image editor in java

Tags: java, image, swing, editor

I'm attempting to develop an image editor in Java. Part of my Java image implementation of the image editor is to load an image and draw some shapes in addition to performing rotation, scaling, etc.

I'm using JLabel to load images but is there a way to draw and apply transformation on an image using JLabel? All of the examples I've found online used JPanel.

Comment: You want to combine object and vector drawing? What have you tried? What have you looked at? Please update your question to be more constructive.

Answer (score 5):

You really need to look at [Java2D turorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html). You should draw images on `Graphics2D` and also rotate and scale images on `Graphics2D`.

***Don't use `JLabel`, because***

- *J-* Components are heavy (although `JLabel` is light-weighted). You can add an icon to a JLabel, but generally, they are used in stable cases, which won't be changed
  frequently and arbitrarily. Painting on a J-* component brings
  too many changes on it.*
- *If you add a great number of components, it will also reduce performance.
  (Each component would paint itself in a separate `Graphics` object which belongs to
  it and its container will paint them all and the layout also matters.)*
- *Another drawback is it is sometimes very difficult even impossible to
  do some manipulations on a component or on a couple of components together. For example, what if you want to add two pictures and group them? You need 2 `JLabel`s, 1 `JPanel` (maybe). Then what if you want to draw a line across these two images and group them again?*

**Below are the basic steps:**

1. override `paint` or `paintComponent` method of a component;
2. cast `Graphics` instance to `Graphics2D`;
3. set some rendering attributes of `Graphics2D`;
4. set transform (rotation, scale, etc.) of `Graphics2D`;
5. draw image on `Graphics2D`

A large variety of classes are used, such as `Graphics2D`, `AffineTransform`, `RenderingHints`, `BufferedImage`, `Shape`, etc. and even more methods. I can't describe everything here. Just read the Java2D tutorial. It gives you an overview of the APIs and tells you how to do these things.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm using JLabel to load images but is there away to draw and apply
>   transformation on an image using JLabel?

Not sure exactly what you mean.

But you can simply get the icon of the `JLabel` (which is the image being displayed) do what needs to be done on the icon which we converted to `BufferedImage` and than reapply the icon via `setIcon(..)`.

Here  is a short example hope it helps:

`JLabel` with icon/`BufferedImage` before rotating -45 degrees:

[image]

`JLabel` after icon was got, rotated and re applied via `setIcon(...)`:

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Test {

    private static JLabel imageLabel;
    private static JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

                JPanel panel = new JPanel();

                imageLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(createImage()));//set image of JLabel

                panel.add(imageLabel);

                frame.add(panel);

                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);

                startImageChangeTimer();//creates a timer which will rotate image after 5 seconds
            }

            private void startImageChangeTimer() {
                Timer timer = new Timer(5000, new AbstractAction() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                        //get JLabel Icon and convert to BufferedImage
                        BufferedImage img = getBufferedImageOfIcon(imageLabel.getIcon(), imageLabel.getWidth(), imageLabel.getHeight());
                        //rotate the image
                        img = createTransformedImage(img, -45);
                        //change the labels image
                        imageLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));

                        frame.pack();//resize frame accrodingly
                    }
                });
                timer.setRepeats(false);
                timer.start();
            }
        });
    }

    public static BufferedImage createImage() {
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(100, 50, BufferedImage.TRANSLUCENT);
        Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 20));
        FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
        String text = "Hello world";
        int textWidth = fm.stringWidth(text);
        g2d.drawString(text, (img.getWidth() / 2) - textWidth / 2, img.getHeight() / 2);
        g2d.dispose();
        return img;
    }

    public static BufferedImage getBufferedImageOfIcon(Icon icon, int imgW, int imgH) {
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(imgW, imgH, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) img.getGraphics();
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        icon.paintIcon(null, g2d, 0, 0);
        g2d.dispose();
        return img;
    }

    public static BufferedImage createTransformedImage(BufferedImage image, double angle) {
        double sin = Math.abs(Math.sin(angle));
        double cos = Math.abs(Math.cos(angle));
        int originalWidth = image.getWidth();
        int originalHeight = image.getHeight();
        int newWidth = (int) Math.floor(originalWidth * cos + originalHeight * sin);
        int newHeight = (int) Math.floor(originalHeight * cos + originalWidth * sin);
        BufferedImage rotatedBI = new BufferedImage(newWidth, newHeight, BufferedImage.TRANSLUCENT);
        Graphics2D g2d = rotatedBI.createGraphics();
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.translate((newWidth - originalWidth) / 2, (newHeight - originalHeight) / 2);
        g2d.rotate(angle, originalWidth / 2, originalHeight / 2);
        g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        g2d.dispose();
        return rotatedBI;
    }
}
```

**Update:**

I do tend to agree with @shuangwhywhy. Draw image to `JPanel` via `paintComponent(Graphics g)` thus you can simply resize the image and set it to the `JPanel` image (via *getters and setters*)and than call `repaint()` to show the changes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is Simple Image Editor

```
  /*Arpana*/
  CPanel displayPanel;

  JButton sharpenButton, blurringButton, edButton, resetButton;

  public ConvolveApp()
    super();
    Container container = getContentPane();

    displayPanel = new CPanel();
    container.add(displayPanel);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
    panel
        .setBorder(new TitledBorder(
            "Click a Button to Perform the Associated Operation and Reset..."));

    sharpenButton = new JButton("Sharpen");
    sharpenButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    blurringButton = new JButton("Blur");
    blurringButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    edButton = new JButton("Edge Detect");
    edButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    resetButton = new JButton("Reset");
    resetButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

    panel.add(sharpenButton);
    panel.add(blurringButton);
    panel.add(edButton);
    panel.add(resetButton);

    container.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, panel);

    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
      public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {

    setSize(displayPanel.getWidth(), displayPanel.getHeight() + 10);
    setVisible(true); 

  public static void main(String arg[]) {
    new ConvolveApp();


  class ButtonListener implements ActionListener 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
      JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();

      if (button.equals(sharpenButton)) 
        displayPanel.sharpen();
        displayPanel.repaint();
       else if (button.equals(blurringButton)) 
        displayPanel.blur();
        displayPanel.repaint();
       else if (button.equals(edButton)) 
        displayPanel.edgeDetect();
        displayPanel.repaint();
      else if (button.equals(resetButton)) 
        displayPanel.reset();
        displayPanel.repaint();


class CPanel extends JLabel 
  Image displayImage;

  BufferedImage biSrc;

  BufferedImage biDest; 

  BufferedImage bi; 

  Graphics2D big;

  CPanel()
    setBackground(Color.black);
    loadImage();
    setSize(displayImage.getWidth(this), displayImage.getWidth(this)); 
    createBufferedImages();
    bi = biSrc;


  public void loadImage() 
    displayImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("Arpana.jpg");
    MediaTracker mt = new MediaTracker(this);
    mt.addImage(displayImage, 1);
    try
      mt.waitForAll();
       if (displayImage.getWidth(this) == -1) 
      System.out.println("No jpg file");
      System.exit(0);


  public void createBufferedImages() 
    biSrc = new BufferedImage(displayImage.getWidth(this), displayImage
        .getHeight(this), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    big = biSrc.createGraphics();
    big.drawImage(displayImage, 0, 0, this);

    biDest = new BufferedImage(displayImage.getWidth(this), displayImage
        .getHeight(this), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);


  public void sharpen() 
    float data[] = { -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 9.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f };
    Kernel kernel = new Kernel(3, 3, data);
    ConvolveOp convolve = new ConvolveOp(kernel, ConvolveOp.EDGE_NO_OP,
        null);
    convolve.filter(biSrc, biDest);
    bi = biDest;


  public void blur() 
    float data[] = { 0.0625f, 0.125f, 0.0625f, 0.125f, 0.25f, 0.125f,
        0.0625f, 0.125f, 0.0625f };
    Kernel kernel = new Kernel(3, 3, data);
    ConvolveOp convolve = new ConvolveOp(kernel, ConvolveOp.EDGE_NO_OP,
        null);
    convolve.filter(biSrc, biDest);
    bi = biDest;


    public void edgeDetect() 
    float data[] = { 1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        -1.0f };

    Kernel kernel = new Kernel(3, 3, data);
    ConvolveOp convolve = new ConvolveOp(kernel, ConvolveOp.EDGE_NO_OP,
        null);
    convolve.filter(biSrc, biDest);

public void reset()
    big.setColor(Color.black);
    big.clearRect(0, 0, bi.getWidth(this), bi.getHeight(this));
    big.drawImage(displayImage, 0, 0, this);
    bi = biSrc;


  public void update(Graphics g) 
    g.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    paintComponent(g);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have only heard of people using JLabels to accomplish this. I recommend displaying the `BufferedImage` as the background of the JLabel. When the user applies an edit to the image, edit the image (If you don't already have a library for manipulating images, I strongly recommend [imgscalr](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/imgscalr-java-image-scaling-library/)) and reapply it as the background of the JLabel (if it doesn't automatically update).

Comment: Read more APIs, java2d is embedded in jdk, for example, working with images: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/index.html And JLabel is really not an option.

Answer (score 0):

```
      /* Arpana*/   
     import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Container;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Graphics2D;
    import java.awt.GridLayout;
    import java.awt.Image;
    import java.awt.MediaTracker;
    import java.awt.Toolkit;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
    import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    import java.awt.image.ConvolveOp;
    import java.awt.image.Kernel;

    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

    public class ConvolveApp extends JFrame {
      CPanel displayPanel;

      JButton sharpenButton, blurringButton, edButton, resetButton;

      public ConvolveApp() {
        super();
        Container container = getContentPane();

        displayPanel = new CPanel();
        container.add(displayPanel);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
        panel
            .setBorder(new TitledBorder(
                "Click a Button to Perform the Associated Operation and Reset..."));

        sharpenButton = new JButton("Sharpen");
        sharpenButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        blurringButton = new JButton("Blur");
        blurringButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        edButton = new JButton("Edge Detect");
        edButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        resetButton = new JButton("Reset");
        resetButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

        panel.add(sharpenButton);
        panel.add(blurringButton);
        panel.add(edButton);
        panel.add(resetButton);

        container.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, panel);

        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
          public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
          }
        });
        setSize(displayPanel.getWidth(), displayPanel.getHeight() + 10);
        setVisible(true); 
      }
      public static void main(String arg[]) {
        new ConvolveApp();
      }

      class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();

          if (button.equals(sharpenButton)) {
            displayPanel.sharpen();
            displayPanel.repaint();
          } else if (button.equals(blurringButton)) {
            displayPanel.blur();
            displayPanel.repaint();
          } else if (button.equals(edButton)) {
            displayPanel.edgeDetect();
            displayPanel.repaint();
          } else if (button.equals(resetButton)) {
            displayPanel.reset();
            displayPanel.repaint();
          }
        }
      }
    }

    class CPanel extends JLabel {
      Image displayImage;

      BufferedImage biSrc;

      BufferedImage biDest; // Destination image is mandetory.

      BufferedImage bi; // Only an additional reference.

      Graphics2D big;

      CPanel() {
        setBackground(Color.black);
        loadImage();
        setSize(displayImage.getWidth(this), displayImage.getWidth(this)); 
        createBufferedImages();
        bi = biSrc;
      }

      public void loadImage() {
        displayImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("Arpana.jpg");
        MediaTracker mt = new MediaTracker(this);
        mt.addImage(displayImage, 1);
        try {
          mt.waitForAll();
        } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println("Exception while loading.");
        }
        if (displayImage.getWidth(this) == -1) {
          System.out.println("No jpg file");
          System.exit(0);
        }
      }

      public void createBufferedImages() {
        biSrc = new BufferedImage(displayImage.getWidth(this), displayImage
            .getHeight(this), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        big = biSrc.createGraphics();
        big.drawImage(displayImage, 0, 0, this);

        biDest = new BufferedImage(displayImage.getWidth(this), displayImage
            .getHeight(this), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
      }

      public void sharpen() {
        float data[] = { -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 9.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
            -1.0f };
        Kernel kernel = new Kernel(3, 3, data);
        ConvolveOp convolve = new ConvolveOp(kernel, ConvolveOp.EDGE_NO_OP,
            null);
        convolve.filter(biSrc, biDest);
        bi = biDest;
      }

      public void blur() {
        float data[] = { 0.0625f, 0.125f, 0.0625f, 0.125f, 0.25f, 0.125f,
            0.0625f, 0.125f, 0.0625f };
        Kernel kernel = new Kernel(3, 3, data);
        ConvolveOp convolve = new ConvolveOp(kernel, ConvolveOp.EDGE_NO_OP,
            null);
        convolve.filter(biSrc, biDest);
        bi = biDest;
      }

        public void edgeDetect() {
        float data[] = { 1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
            -1.0f };

        Kernel kernel = new Kernel(3, 3, data);
        ConvolveOp convolve = new ConvolveOp(kernel, ConvolveOp.EDGE_NO_OP,
            null);
        convolve.filter(biSrc, biDest);

        bi = biDest;
      }

      public void reset() {
        big.setColor(Color.black);
        big.clearRect(0, 0, bi.getWidth(this), bi.getHeight(this));
        big.drawImage(displayImage, 0, 0, this);
        bi = biSrc;
      }

      public void update(Graphics g) {
        g.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        paintComponent(g);
      }

      public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2D.drawImage(bi, 0, 0, this);
      }
    }
```